# iptables -j TPROXY in suse(kernel version 3.0.101) :No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables

I want to redirect all udp packet use tproxy in suse(kernel:3.0.101),I do this:

1.iptables -t mangle -N SHADOWSOCKS_UDP

2.iptables -t mangle -N SHADOWSOCKS_UDP_MARK

3.ip route add local default dev lo table 100

4.ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100

and `iptables -t mangle -L` shows :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUIZt.png)

5:iptables -t mangle -A SHADOWSOCKS_UDP -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 3386 --tproxy-mark 0x01/0x01

and get error:
**iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.**

I do not know why? Thank you very much give me some advice.

and this is my tproxy config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5GQA.png)

**And those command works well in ubuntu(kernel version:4.4.0)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. finsh it.  it  because  suse  dose not..have  xt_TPROXY  kernel  module.  you  need to compile  kernel  module.  and  insmod it.